# How to deal with EGL while porting OpenGL ES application to native OpenGL program

Tags: opengl-es, egl

Starting from yesterday, I'm porting an OpenGL ES program written in Objective-C to native OpenGL program running on Linux and the thing is that I don't know how to deal with EAGL context. Is there any problem if I just simply ignore EAGL context and carry on implementing the native OpenGL program? If not, let me know how to deal with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without some alternative to EAGL you're not going to have a window surface to render into, so ignoring it isn't an option.

Assuming you are running on desktop and X for the your windowing system, then look at the GLX API (but there are alternative - mesa have an EGL implementation, some Linux distros are staring to ship Wayland rather than X, so GLX won't work, etc).

In general for getting started I'd recommend web searching for OpenGL tutorials for your particular flavour of Linux.

Comment: The linux I am using is Ubuntu 14.04. Is the linux support x windowing system?